# How to encrypt email messages and attachments without using an extension in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, encryption

Can anyone tell me how to encrypt Gmail messages and attachments without having to use an extension? I have come across a few extensions for Google Chrome and Firefox doing the encryption but the receiver would have to install the extension too in order to decipher. Therefore, I would really like to know if there is a way to encrypt your Gmail message without an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this support site helps you: [Email encryption in transit - Gmail Help - Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6330403?hl=en)

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can add essential content from link into answer.